# Is this a sphere parametrization $\Bbb{S}^2 \subset \Bbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I was reading the article of A Venttsel - On boundary condition for multidimensional diffusion processes and he says the following

[image]

I don't understand what he is saying. Here is the picture in my mind:

[image]

My question is Is this picture an appropriate interpretation of the author's text? 
If so, what is the parametrization function: $T:(-\pi,\pi) \times (0,\pi) \to \Bbb{S}^2$

Comment: It seems that this is just ordinary spherical coordinates, but using $\omega_0$ in place of the $z$-axis.

Comment: what is the plane perpendicular to $w_0$?

Comment: I don't know all the details in the article, but if you choose any two mutually orthogonal vectors $u$, $v$ that are each orthogonal to $\omega_0$, then the subspace spanned by $u$, $v$ is a plane orthogonal to $\omega_0$.

Comment: Yes I would say that $\pi_{w_0}^{\bot} = \{w, \langle w,w_0\rangle = 0\}$ but this is not the usual plane of the parametrization $\phi(x,y) = (\sin x\cos y, \cos x\cos y,\sin y)$, its strange...

Comment: It's just a different basis. Instead of $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$ you can choose another orthonormal set of three vectors. Just make one of them in the direction of $\omega_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above picture is correct.

A possible parametrization in this case would be (in the case $w_0 = (0,0,1)$) (Note that since the initial side that we choose in the perpendicular plane is arbitrary, one might get several different parametrizations)

\begin{align}T:(0,1)\times (0,\pi)\times (-\pi ,\pi)&\to \Bbb{R}^3 \\
r,\theta,\phi &\mapsto(r\sin \theta\sin \phi, r \sin \theta\cos \phi, r\cos \theta )\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Consider the usual spherical coordinates in terms of
the Cartesian coordinates $x$, $y$, and $z$.
Now instead of the basis $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$
on which the usual spherical coordinates are defined,
choose an orthonormal set of three vectors such that the third vector
(the one that replaces $\hat z$) is in the direction of $\omega_0$.
This gives you a new coordinate system over $\mathbb R^3$.

The same equations that gave you spherical coordinates in terms
of $x$, $y$, and $z$ can give you spherical coordinates in terms
of your new orthonormal basis; just substitute the new coordinates 
for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

I think the $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinates in the paper are just
spherical coordinates in terms of an orthonormal basis
with its third vector in the direction of $\omega_0$.

The paper also seems to be using an engineering convention rather than
the usual mathematical convention for choosing which angle to call
$\theta$ and which to call $\phi$. That is, if you look at
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html (for example),
you see that there $\phi$ rather than $\theta$ measures an angle
between a vector and an axis. But it's clear from the description that
this paper is using the symbol $\theta$ for the corresponding angle
in its parameterization.

Comment: The engineering convention for $\theta$ and $\phi$ is also the usual one in physics.  Not sure if there are other fields which use spherical coordinates on a regular basis;  astronomy does, I suppose, but they like to measure their polar angles relative to equatorial planes.

Comment: fix $w_0 = (0,1,0)$ to be in the usual setting. what is the perpendicular plane? I guess it is $\pi=\{(x,1,z), x,z \in \Bbb{R}\}$ how do you measure your angle with resect to this plane? I believe my drawing is pretty different from the one in Wolphran's page. What do you think?

Comment: I think you're better off setting $\omega_0 = (0,0,1),$ not $(0,1,0)$. People do not usually use the $y$ axis as the axis of symmetry for spherical coordinates.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I do a lot of work with geodetic coordinates (latitude and longitude) which also measure the polar angle from the equator. (But I think we agree that's clearly not the intention in the article in question here.)

Comment: Still @DavidK, I think you insist in the fact that this is just a basis rotation of the usual parametrization. I think this is not the case. Let $w_0 = (0,0,1)$. What is the perpendicular plane? I would say that this is $\pi=\{(x,y,1), x,y \in \Bbb{R}\}$. Take the point $w =(1,0,0)$. what is the angle between $w_0$ and $w$? What is the angle in the perpendicular plane?

Comment: I mean, you might be right that this is what the author meant, but this is not what he is saying. At least I don't see it.

Comment: Try $\pi=\{(x,y,0)\}$ instead. The vectors $(x,y,0)$ are all perpendicular to $(0,0,1)$. None of the vectors $(x,y,1)$ are.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, The drawing above is right, it gives the canonical spherical parametrization you were talking about.  (Affine translations were not at all the problem, but determining the angle $\varphi$). Thank you, for your attention.